# What is the path of data transfer when using memory mapped file?

Tags: linux, io, mmap, memory-mapped-file

Is there any difference between the data transfer paths using read()/write() and using mmap() on a file?

What does "kernel" mean in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41419353?

> mmap doesn't require a copy of the file data from **kernel** to user-space.

Is it correct that read() copies data from file to a buffer in kernel space , then from the kernel buffer to a buffer in user space?

When calling mmap() on a file, does it map virtual memory addresses directly to the file, without anything (e.g. a buffer in kernel space) in between?

When accessing virtual memory addresses returned by mmap(), what is the path for data transfer? Is there any buffer in kernel space involved in the middle behind the scene?

Does mmap() have an advantage  over read()/write(), as far as data transfer path is concerned?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any difference between the data transfer paths using read()/write() and using mmap() on a file?

Yes, see below for details.

> What does "kernel" mean in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41419353?
>
> > mmap doesn't require a copy of the file data from **kernel** to user-space.

This refers to memory mapped in the kernel’s address space.

> Is it correct that read() copies data from file to a buffer in kernel space , then from the kernel buffer to a buffer in user space?

Yes, and it has to: `read` reads into a user space-provided buffer, with no alignment constraints, and the data is supposed to be completely dissociated from the file descriptor once it’s been read. So the kernel reads whatever data is required to fulfill the `read` (if any — the data might already be in the page cache, or in a pipe buffer, or …), and then copies the requested data into the user space-provided buffer.

> When accessing virtual memory addresses returned by mmap(), what is the path for data transfer? Is there any buffer in kernel space involved in the middle behind the scene?

When the mapping is file-backed, the data is read into the page cache, and the kernel allows the `mmap`ping process to access the corresponding physical pages in memory directly (through a separate page map). There is no buffer involved behind the scenes, at least as long as the process doesn’t write to the pages (and the behaviour then depends on the `mmap` flags).

> Does mmap() have an advantage over read()/write(), as far as data transfer path is concerned?

This is already discussed in detail in [the SO question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45972/4500798). `mmap` avoids some copying, but whether it’s better overall than `read`/`write` depends on the details of what the caller is doing.

In some circumstances, other system calls on Linux will provide better performance; see for example [`sendfile`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html), [`copy_file_range`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/copy_file_range.2.html), and [`splice`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html).